# confidence intervals for expected spending

Tags: statistics

A random sample of 10 motorists buying petrol are found to spend an average of £58.30 with estimated standard error £5.25.  Calculate a 95% confidence interval for the expected spending of motorists at this petrol station.

I got 10 of these questions so if someone can help me do this one i think i can do the rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the formula to calculate a confidence interval, given a mean, standard deviation and sample size?

Comment: Z(a/2) * standard deviation/ square root of sample size I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your interval is defined by $$\left(\overline x-z^*\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}},\space\overline x+z^*\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}\right)$$ You already know $\overline x = 58.3, \space N=10, \space\sigma = 5.25$. Your $z^*$ value is determined by how wide you want your confidence interval. Since you want a $95\%$ interval and know that  $95\%$ of a normally distributed population is contained within $1.96$ standard deviations from the mean, you want $z^* = 1.96$. The rest is just a matter of plugging in numbers. Your sample size is extremely small, so you may also want to make a note of that in your answer.

Comment: Cheers, This is a lot of help. Thanks mate.

Comment: Glad to help; please accept my answer if you have no further questions and don't need any more help :)